# Can't run npx create-react-app my-app: "throw err0-" errno: -4048, syscall: 'mkdir', code: 'EPERM'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

I'm trying to run ''npx create-react-app my-new-app' on Windows and have hit the error below, help would be appreciated.

For context, I first ran `npx create-react-app my-new-app` had an issue because my user name has whitespace (Smart User) so I ran `npm i -g create-react-app` and then tried again - which gave this error:

```
$ npx create-react-app my-new-app
C:\Users\Smart User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:45
        throw err0
        ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\Git\my-new-app'        
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:921:3)
    at Object.mkdirsSync (C:\Users\Smart User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:31:9)
    at createApp (C:\Users\Smart User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:230:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Smart User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:187:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18) {
  errno: -4048,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\my-new-app'
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a permission issue regarding the folder where you are trying to create the app, which is under `C:\Program Files\Git`

Can you try create it in another folder? Preferably something under your user folder (commonly `C:\Users\yourusername\`)

Comment: @EduardoReveles Thanks!
Ran `npm i create-react-app` in a folder a couple of levels below my user folder, then `npx create-react-app my-new-app` in the folder. All good!